# How can I read and set the paper style (aka papername) in Firemonkey MacOS

Tags: macos, delphi, printing, firemonkey

Working in Delphi Firemonkey for Mac OS64.

Trying to read and then set the variable Apple calls the "paperName", which is the paper type (letter, legal, envelope, etc.)  I know that it is accessed through NSPrinter.PaperName? but I do not understand how to code FMX to access it.

I'm using cookbooked code to get the paper rectangle:

```
FPrintInfo := TNSPrintInfo.Wrap(TNSPrintInfo.OCClass.sharedPrintInfo);
FPrintInfo.retain;
PMGetAdjustedPaperRect(FPrintInfo.PMPageFormat, @PaperRect);
FPrintInfo.release;
```

but I'm not experienced at all with Mac code so my attempts to plug-and-play off of this code to get papername have not been successful.

Thanks for your help.

Dave,

Thanks.  Sorry, I didn't really give you enough info.  The code I provided does work, to get the paper rectangle.

What I am trying to get, in addition, is the paper name, and I can't figure out what function will get me that.

I'm trying to use PMGetPageFormatPaper(FPrintInfo.PMPageFormat, @PaperTypeS); but I think I may not be declaring PaperTypeS correctly.

What I'm trying is:

```
function getPaperShape: string;
var
FPrintInfo: NSPrintInfo;
PaperRect: PMRect;
paperwidth,paperheight:double;
paperTypeS:string;
begin
FPrintInfo := TNSPrintInfo.Wrap(TNSPrintInfo.OCClass.sharedPrintInfo);
FPrintInfo.retain;
PMGetAdjustedPaperRect(FPrintInfo.PMPageFormat, @PaperRect);
PMGetPageFormatPaper(FPrintInfo.PMPageFormat, @PaperTypeS);  
FPrintInfo.release;
paperwidth:= PaperRect.right-PaperRect.left;
paperheight:= PaperRect.bottom-PaperRect.top;
end;
```

That clearly is not correct, since I get nothing returned in paperTypeS.  I've tried declaring paperTypeS as NSPrinter.PaperName, or just as PaperName, or as PMPaperName, but clearly I'm just guessing here and none of those are recognized by FMX as valid types.

Does that make more sense?

Again, thanks.

Scott

Comment: You're missing how you have declared PaperRect. If it's: PaperRect: PMRect (note only one P in PMRect), then your code *should* work, however you have not indicated what the result is. PS: You should not need the calls to retain and release.

Comment: edited above.  Sorry, I apparently can't use StackOverflow correctly since my answer to you came out as part of my original question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just remembered that some of the printer functions are implemented in the FMX.Printer.Mac unit. You could examine the source there, which includes what you're doing

Comment: Thanks.  I will look.  This was not available when I first designed the project a few years back, but I have not looked at recent versions of FMX.

Comment: Sorry, it does look like it offers more than it used to, but I see no reference to PaperName in that unit.  Am I missing it?